# Cannot use RandomSample to get a sample bigger than the original

Tags: list-manipulation, random, sampling

I have a sample of 300 elements and I need a random vector of size 100000 which consists of random repetitions of the elements of the 300-element sample

I have tried the following

```
RandomSample[valueVector, 100000];
```

which returns the error

```
RandomSample::smplen: RandomSample cannot generate a sample of length 100000, which is greater than the length of the sample set {24741.5,20716.6,20850.3,20405.7,22293.1,46828.8,18963.4,25654.3,20767.4,22529.1,<<31>>,24440.8,22442.4,21309.6,25205.9,20810.9,20757.4,23551.3,22783.4,22674.8,<<250>>}. If you want a choice of possibly repeated elements from the set, use RandomChoice.
```

Can someone please suggest me how can I do this? should I use the `RandomSample` 333 times or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I voted to close this as "easily found in the documentation". If you are not yet used to checking the Details sections of the docs, make a habit of always looking there.

Comment: A shame, the OP didn't even read the error, which includes *"If you want a choice of possibly repeated elements from the set, use `RandomChoice`"*. Reading the documentation and all error codes surely takes less effort than posting a question.

Answer (score 2):

Try `RandomChoice`

```
RandomChoice[valueVector , 100000 ]
```

Answer (score -2):

I have managed with

```
RV = ConstantArray[1, 100000];
SeedRandom[1234];

For[i = 1, i < 100001, i++, 
  RV[[i]] = RandomChoice[valueVector]];
```

Comment: Since you are a beginner, it will be useful for your learning to completely forget that `For` loops even exist in Mathematica. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/12